# how to write replace and redirect url with post data rules in apache 2.4 RewriteRule (both simultaneously)?

Tags: apache2, apache2.4, apache2.2

We can use below reference
1. [Replacing %23 in URL with # using mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921602/replacing-23-in-url-with-using-mod-rewrite)
2.[Redirection on Apache (Maintain POST params)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17295085/redirection-on-apache-maintain-post-params)

1. first url use for replace url [R]. old to new url. like example:

www.cashcon.com/group/desk/  to www.cashcon.com/desk/

2.second url use for redirect url with post data.using [p]
like example www.cashcon.com/desk/ to lolcalhost:8080/desk

-> Both are work in separately. But both functionality not work simultaneously.
-> How to write [R and P] both rules combin ?
-> Any other rules available for replace and redirect with post data for RewriteRule in apache 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine these flags in one rule, they are mutually exclusive. But there's also really no reason to. Every time you use the [P] flag to proxy, you are creating a substitute URL.

Either substitute the URL you want for the [P] rule, or redirect to a new URL and proxy when the user returns after the redirect.

Comment: Instead Proxy [p] rule  we have used  ProxyHTMLURLMap for replace url.

Comment: @MisterD if the answer is helpful and solves your problem, please consider accepting it as well as upvoting.